# Two-column list

Tags: enumerate, matrices

Does anybody here know how to generate a two-column list like the one that appears in the attached image? I'm having a hard time making the matrices look as neatly aligned as in the shared image...

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

The next code was using the matrix environment within the multicol package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Determinar la transpuesta de cada una de las sigientes matrices. Adem\'as si la matriz es cuadrada, calcular su traza.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item   
            $\left( \begin{matrix}
            -4 & 2 \\
            5 & -1
            \end{matrix} \right)$
            \item           
            $\left( \begin{matrix}
            0 & 8 & -6 \\
            3 & 4 & 7 
            \end{matrix} \right)$
            \item 
            $\left( \begin{matrix}
            -3 & 9 \\
            0 & -2 \\
            6 & 1 
            \end{matrix} \right)$
            \item 
            $\left( \begin{matrix}
            10 & 0 & -8 \\
            2 & -4 & 3 \\
            -5 & 7 & 6 
            \end{matrix} \right)$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you add a second row of matrices therein?

Comment: just add \\ at the end of the row, there you go with those matrices you can do the rest of them

Comment: The enumeration won't increase horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that wraps each matrix in a `minipage` and the `resume` feature of [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem):

[image]

If you wish to align the labels with the top, then you can use `adjustbox`:

[image]

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{MatrixCount}
\setcounter{MatrixCount}{0}

\newenvironment{MyMatrix}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
         \ifnum\arabic{MatrixCount}=0 
             \smallskip
             \begin{enumerate}[series=MyList]
             \stepcounter{MatrixCount}%
         \else
             \begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyList]
         \fi
         \item  $\begin{pmatrix}
}{%
                \end{pmatrix}$%
        \end{enumerate}%
    \end{minipage}%
     \ifnum\arabic{MatrixCount}=2
         \par
         \setcounter{MatrixCount}{0}%
     \fi 
     \stepcounter{MatrixCount}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Here are a some matrices.
    
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            -4 & 2 \\
            5 & -1
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            0 & 8 & -6 \\
            3 & 4 & 7 
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            -3 & 9 \\
            0 & -2 \\
            6 & 1 
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            10 & 0 & -8 \\
            2 & -4 & 3 \\
            -5 & 7 & 6 
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            1 & -1 & 3 & 5 \\
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            -2 & 5 & 1 & 4 \\
            7 & 0 & 1 & -6 \\
        \end{MyMatrix}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code `adjustbox` to align labels at top

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{MatrixCount}
\setcounter{MatrixCount}{0}

\newenvironment{MyMatrix}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
         \ifnum\arabic{MatrixCount}=0 
             \smallskip
             \begin{enumerate}[series=MyList]
             \stepcounter{MatrixCount}%
         \else
             \begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyList]
         \fi
         \item  \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
                 $\begin{pmatrix}
}{%
                \end{pmatrix}$%
                \end{adjustbox}%
        \end{enumerate}%
    \end{minipage}%
     \ifnum\arabic{MatrixCount}=2
         \par
         \setcounter{MatrixCount}{0}%
     \fi 
     \stepcounter{MatrixCount}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Here are a some matrices.
    
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            -4 & 2 \\
            5 & -1
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            0 & 8 & -6 \\
            3 & 4 & 7 
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            -3 & 9 \\
            0 & -2 \\
            6 & 1 
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            10 & 0 & -8 \\
            2 & -4 & 3 \\
            -5 & 7 & 6 
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            1 & -1 & 3 & 5 \\
        \end{MyMatrix}
        % ------------- No blank line here.
        \begin{MyMatrix}
            -2 & 5 & 1 & 4 \\
            7 & 0 & 1 & -6 \\
        \end{MyMatrix}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a left-to-right anumeration, `the`tasks package is done for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{ label-offset=0.85em,counter-format =(tsk[a]) , column-sep =8pt, item-indent=4em, after-item-skip=0.6ex, after-skip=3ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
    \item Determinar la transpuesta de cada una de las sigientes matrices. Adem\'as si la matriz es cuadrada, calcular su traza.
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            -4 & 2 \\
            5 & -1
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & 8 & -6 \\
            3 & 4 & 7
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            -3 & 9 \\
            0 & -2 \\
            6 & 1
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            10 & 0 & -8 \\
            2 & -4 & 3 \\
            -5 & 7 & 6
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & -1 & 3 & 5
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            -2 & 5 & 1 & 4\\
            7 & 0 & 1 & -6
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            -5 \\ 0 \\ 7
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \task
            $ \begin{pmatrix}
            -& 0 &6\\
            0 & 1 & -1\\
            6 & -3 & 5
            \end{pmatrix} $
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]